# How to use `List` on different iOS devices

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationsplitview

I'm developing a SwiftUI application that should work on iPad and iPhone devices, but I have a problem with using `List`. I have attached photos for the expected behavior I need from the `List`.

I also have tried using `NavigationSplitView` but it does not select items in the list.

**This is my code:**

```swift
struct VehicleListView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: VehicleUserViewModel = VehicleUserViewModel()
    @State private var tappedVehicle: VehicleModel?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List(viewModel.vehicles, id: \.id) { vehicle in
                HStack {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(vehicle.brand ?? "")
                            .bold()
                            .foregroundStyle(.blue)
                        
                        Text(vehicle.plateId ?? "")
                    }
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                        .imageScale(.large)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Araçlar")
        } detail: {
            if let vehicle = tappedVehicle {
                CustomVehicleView(fetchedVehicle: Binding(get: {
                    vehicle
                }, set: { newValue in
                    tappedVehicle = newValue
                }))
            } else {
                EmptyView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is how the list is displayed on the Settings app on iPhone devices. When clicked on a list element, it navigates you to the page related to that element. [(See image here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xwrH.png)

This is how to use the list on the settings page on iPad devices. When a list element is clicked, the page related to that element opens right next to the page. [(See image here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxE7p.png)

How is this used? Does the SwiftUI code adjust this usage based on the type of device?

Comment: To implement exactly that you would need to show one of two different root views, depending on whether you detect an iPhone or an iPad. You can use a [`NavigationSplitView`](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/building-lists-and-navigation) to do it more easily, but you do end up with a slightly different UI on iPad; the left hand list can be hidden.

Comment: That was the standard navigation with NavigationView but it is now deprecated.

Comment: What is your minimum target?

Comment: I want the application to work responsively on at least iOS 16 and iPadOS 16. Actually, all I want is for the relevant page to appear on the side when I click on the element of the list on the iPad, as in the picture. On iPhone, it will navigate to the relevant page.

Answer (score 0):

If you need support for `iOS 16.0+`, use [`NavigationSplitView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationsplitview), it does exactly what you're asking for:

```swift
@State private var vehicle: Vehicle? = nil

init() {
    self.vehicle = viewModel.vehicles[0]
}


var body: some View {
    NavigationSplitView {
        List(viewModel.vehicles,
             selection: $vehicle) { v in
            Text(v.brand)
        }
    } detail: {
        CustomVehicleView(fetchedVehicle: $vehicle)
    }
}
```

> **Ensure your `Vehicle` conforms to `Identifiable` or/and `Hashable` in order for you to be able to use `List(_:selection:rowContent:)`:**

Comment: this is good but when I click on the element of the list, I want to send the relevant employee to the EmployeeDetails page. How can I do that?

Comment: @MehmetÖzkan The code snippet I provided already does that. Please read the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationsplitview). And Mark this as the answer if it answers your questions please.

Comment: Not exactly what I want. I am sharing my code in the question, can you take a look?

Comment: You're not implementing it as you should. I have edited my answer.